# Excel string to duration

Tags: excel, string, time, duration

I've a date duration of "2d 8h56m23s".  I want to add different duration of this type.

My first idea was to transform to date format but I can never add to duration. 
I've also used this to change the type, but the sum doesn't work.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;"d";"");"h";":");"m";":");"s";"")
```

Example:

```
2d 8h56m23s + 0d 11h00m00s

= 2d 19h56m23s
```

Comment: Are those text entries, or numbers with a Custom Format of d"d"  h"h"m"m"s"s"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming values in A2 and B2, I suggest in two stages (though the formulae might be combined into a very long one):

1. As your approach, say in C2 and copied cross to D2:

   ```
   =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;"h";":");"m";":");"d";"");"s";"")
   ```

Then 2. (in E2 and copied across to F2):

```
=LEFT(C2;FIND(" ";C2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(C2;FIND(" ";C2);25))
```

These may then be treated as numbers and, for example, added, presumably with the formatting as suggested by XOR LX:

```
d"d" h"h"m"m"s"s"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already accept the answer from @pnuts, I took a similar route but went for a single formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND("d";A2));"h";":");"m";":");"s";""))+LEFT(FIND("d";A2);FIND("d";A2)-1)
```

This will give the duration as a decimal which you can then sum and format as required.